# Retrieving specific elements from an XDocument based on a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a list of xml elements stored in a class:

```
public class clsField
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am loading an xml file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

Finally I want to retrieve only the fields defined in the above class into a IEnumerable object.   This is what I have so far:

```
List<clsField> lstFieldsToProcess;          
IEnumerable<XElement> allthedocs = from thedoc
                 in doc.Descendants("thedocs")
                 select
                 (
                  from fields
                  in lstFieldsToProcess
                  select XElement.Parse(fields.fieldName)
                 );
```

But am getting an error on the above code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks before hand.

**Update #1**

Pseudo code:

```
var fieldNames = new HashSet<string>(lstFieldsToProcess.Select(c => c.fieldName));
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = from level1 in doc.Elements("thedocs")
                              let level2 = level1.Descendants()
                              where fieldNames.Contains(level2.Name.LocalName)
                              select level1;
```

Comment: `getting an error on the above code` how about sharing it with us?

Comment: Is `clsField` the object that is serialized into the `fileName` document? Or do you have an arbitrary object serialized, and you want to get to the property names of *another* class (in this case class `clsField`), and only retrieve fields from the xml document that match the property names found in `clsField`?

Comment: The latter is correct.  clsField is a separate class that contains the property name of the fields I would like to retrieve from "XDocument doc".  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you try to do. Do you want to filter out all elements with a certain name and that is descendant of the element(s) named "thedocs"?

Assuming that is what you want to do, then you could do the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = from field in lstFieldsToProcess
                              from de in doc.Elements("thedocs").Descendants(field.fieldName)
                              select de;

// Of course this is the same:
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = lstFieldsToProcess
    .SelectMany(f => doc.Elements("thedocs").Descendants(f.fieldName));
```

I am not sure how efficient XDocument is though, so perhaps it is better to take out the fieldnames you want to match first (please test which is the better of the two if performance is important to you):

```
var fieldNames = new HashSet<string>(lstFieldsToProcess.Select(c => c.fieldName));
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = from d in doc.Elements("thedocs").Descendants()
                              where fieldNames.Contains(d.Name.LocalName)
                              select d;
```

**Update #1**
I think almost have it yourself in your pseudocode.

```
var fieldNames = new HashSet<string>(lstFieldsToProcess.Select(c => c.fieldName));
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = from level1 in doc.Elements("thedocs")
                              from level2 in level1.Descendants()
                              where fieldNames.Contains(level2.Name.LocalName)
                              select level1;
```

Though, this can contain same "thedocs" element many times (if it has several descendants with valid fieldname). To avoid that, just call Distint() on the result.

Comment: Kennet thanks! Almost there.  It does correctly select the fields from the descendants. Now how do I get back: "doc.Elements("thedocs")" instead of "doc.Elements("thedocs").Descendants"?  The fields are selected but the final format I need is just "doc.Elements("thedocs")".  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertSmith: What do you mean with "get back"? If you change these elements (e.g. Value) in any way they are actually changed in your doc variable in memory as well. So to get the new xml (with changed values) as strings (one per "theDocs" element) you can simply do:    
`doc.Elements("theDocs").Select(e => e.ToString())` 
Of course, if you only have one "theDocs" element you can instead do: `doc.Element("theDocs").ToString()`

Comment: Kennet, it is hard to explain.  See "Update #1" above.  The fields that need to be selected are one level deeper ("level2" above).  But the select statement needs to select "level1".

Comment: Kennet, also forgot to mention "Update #1" above is Pseudo code.  It does not work but it has the basic concept I am looking for.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobertSmith: I updated my answer, hopefully that is what you're after. (sorry for the slow reply).